# angle inequality in n-dimensional vector space

Tags: inequalities, vector-spaces

Does anyone has answer for the following doc product problem?

Let A,B,C be three vectors of magnitude of 1.

Let     A*B = Cos(x)                  ( * means dot product)
        B*C = Cos(y)
        A*C = Cos(z)

For 2 or 3 dimensional space, we have  z <= x + y.

My question is, can we extend this inequality to N-dimensional space?

Answer (score 3):

Any three vectors, like your $A,B,C$, in an $N$-dimensional space lie in a $3$-dimensional subspace. So the general result follows from the $3$-dimensional one.